# Unresolved linker error in winrt/Windows.Gaming.Input.h

Tags: c++-winrt

Although I'm not new to c++ I am new to c++\cli and c++\winrt. I am having an issue when I include `winrt/Windows.Gaming.Input.h` I've searched online for anything I could be missing and I found that I needed to include before the first include `winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h` except that doesn't change the errors I get when building the .dll file. In case it is necessary, at first when added `winrt/Windows.Gaming.Input.h` I got like 3k errors but I fixed by changing the target from c++14 to 17 which boiled it down to the twelve errors below that I can't find what they want.

My errors as follows:

```
1>RawControllerInput.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000B6D) "extern "C" int __cdecl WINRT_IIDFromString(wchar_t const *,struct winrt::guid *)" (?WINRT_IIDFromString@@$$J0YAHPEB_WPEAUguid@winrt@@@Z) referenced in function "public: static __cdecl winrt::impl::natvis::abi_val(void *,wchar_t const *,int)" (?abi_val@natvis@impl@winrt@@$$FSA@PEAXPEB_WH@Z)
1>RawControllerInput.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000B9A) "extern "C" int __cdecl WINRT_RoOriginateLanguageException(int,void *,void *)" (?WINRT_RoOriginateLanguageException@@$$J0YAHHPEAX0@Z) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl winrt::hresult_error::originate(struct winrt::hresult,void *)" (?originate@hresult_error@winrt@@$$FAEAAXUhresult@2@PEAX@Z)
1>RawControllerInput.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000BA1) "extern "C" int __cdecl WINRT_GetRestrictedErrorInfo(void * *)" (?WINRT_GetRestrictedErrorInfo@@$$J0YAHPEAPEAX@Z) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl winrt::hresult_error::originate(struct winrt::hresult,void *)" (?originate@hresult_error@winrt@@$$FAEAAXUhresult@2@PEAX@Z)
1>RawControllerInput.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000BA3) "extern "C" void __cdecl WINRT_SysFreeString(wchar_t *)" (?WINRT_SysFreeString@@$$J0YAXPEA_W@Z) referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl winrt::impl::bstr_traits::close(wchar_t *)" (?close@bstr_traits@impl@winrt@@$$FSAXPEA_W@Z)
1>RawControllerInput.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000BB1) "extern "C" int __cdecl WINRT_WindowsDeleteString(void *)" (?WINRT_WindowsDeleteString@@$$J0YAHPEAX@Z) referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl winrt::impl::hstring_traits::close(void *)" (?close@hstring_traits@impl@winrt@@$$FSAXPEAX@Z)
1>RawControllerInput.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000BB4) "extern "C" int __cdecl WINRT_WindowsDuplicateString(void *,void * *)" (?WINRT_WindowsDuplicateString@@$$J0YAHPEAXPEAPEAX@Z) referenced in function "void * __cdecl winrt::impl::duplicate_string(void *)" (?duplicate_string@impl@winrt@@$$FYAPEAXPEAX@Z)
1>RawControllerInput.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" int __cdecl WINRT_WindowsDeleteString(void *)" (?WINRT_WindowsDeleteString@@$$J0YAHPEAX@Z) referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl winrt::impl::hstring_traits::close(void *)" (?close@hstring_traits@impl@winrt@@$$FSAXPEAX@Z)
1>RawControllerInput.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" void __cdecl WINRT_SysFreeString(wchar_t *)" (?WINRT_SysFreeString@@$$J0YAXPEA_W@Z) referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl winrt::impl::bstr_traits::close(wchar_t *)" (?close@bstr_traits@impl@winrt@@$$FSAXPEA_W@Z)
1>RawControllerInput.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" int __cdecl WINRT_IIDFromString(wchar_t const *,struct winrt::guid *)" (?WINRT_IIDFromString@@$$J0YAHPEB_WPEAUguid@winrt@@@Z) referenced in function "public: static __cdecl winrt::impl::natvis::abi_val(void *,wchar_t const *,int)" (?abi_val@natvis@impl@winrt@@$$FSA@PEAXPEB_WH@Z)
1>RawControllerInput.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" int __cdecl WINRT_RoOriginateLanguageException(int,void *,void *)" (?WINRT_RoOriginateLanguageException@@$$J0YAHHPEAX0@Z) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl winrt::hresult_error::originate(struct winrt::hresult,void *)" (?originate@hresult_error@winrt@@$$FAEAAXUhresult@2@PEAX@Z)
1>RawControllerInput.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" int __cdecl WINRT_GetRestrictedErrorInfo(void * *)" (?WINRT_GetRestrictedErrorInfo@@$$J0YAHPEAPEAX@Z) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl winrt::hresult_error::originate(struct winrt::hresult,void *)" (?originate@hresult_error@winrt@@$$FAEAAXUhresult@2@PEAX@Z)
1>RawControllerInput.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" int __cdecl WINRT_WindowsDuplicateString(void *,void * *)" (?WINRT_WindowsDuplicateString@@$$J0YAHPEAXPEAPEAX@Z) referenced in function "void * __cdecl winrt::impl::duplicate_string(void *)" (?duplicate_string@impl@winrt@@$$FYAPEAXPEAX@Z)
```

If I try and search for any of these functions in my entire project or specifically in the header files, it comes up with nothing so I don't even know if these functions are actually in use. I've also searched for them on google to see what library they're in but I don't see any documentation.

If it is necessary, my code:

```
// RawControllerInput.h
#pragma once
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Gaming.Input.h>

using namespace System;

namespace RawControllerInput {
    public ref class Class1
    {
        // TODO: Add your methods for this class here.
    };
}
```

```
// RawControllerInput.cpp
#include "pch.h"

#include "RawControllerInput.h"
```

```
// pch.h
// pch.h: This is a precompiled header file.
// Files listed below are compiled only once, improving build performance for future builds.
// This also affects IntelliSense performance, including code completion and many code browsing features.
// However, files listed here are ALL re-compiled if any one of them is updated between builds.
// Do not add files here that you will be updating frequently as this negates the performance advantage.

#ifndef PCH_H
#define PCH_H

// add headers that you want to pre-compile here

#endif //PCH_H
```

Comment: That's not C++/CLI. It's C++/CX. I don't know how well it co-exists with C++/WinRT. I also don't know what C++15 is.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes that was a mistype that I didn't catch, I'll fix it and if this is not c++/CLI then I don't know what tutorial I followed was telling me to do because I followed this [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/walkthrough-compiling-a-cpp-program-that-targets-the-clr-in-visual-studio?view=msvc-170) one. The only variation was I chose the DLL project instead of empty one. Additionally how can you tell?

Comment: `ref class` is a C++/CX compound keyword; it doesn't exist in C++/CLI. C++/CLI is useful for native interoperability with .NET. You cannot use C++/CLI to access the Windows Runtime. That's what C++/CX is for. Though, unless you're using XAML, C++/WinRT is an all-around better option. Anyway, the functions are declared in `<winrt/base.h>` and used by C++/WinRT. At one point you'd have to link against *windowsapp.lib*, though I don't know if that is still true. But, since you aren't actually using C++/WinRT you don't even need those headers.

Comment: Somehow you managed to include files from `<cppwinrt/winrt>` (which are C++/WinRT-specific) rather than the headers in the `<winrt>` folder of the SDK. Either way, I'd just start over, scrap C++/CX, and go with [C++/WinRT](https://aka.ms/cppwinrt) instead.

Comment: Guess I was wrong, `ref class` is *also* a compound keyword in C++/CLI. Regardless, you can't access the Windows Runtime using C++/CLI. So starting over is a given.

Comment: @IInspectable To give more context I am trying to access the `RawGameController` class to use it in a C# application. Can C++/WinRT code be called from C#? Or am I doing this backwards?

Comment: A Windows Runtime Component authored using C++/WinRT can be consumed by a program written in C#. This is common practice even; WinUI (2 and 3) are built using C++/WinRT and predominantly used by C# applications. You will want to create a project using the *Windows Runtime Component (C++/WinRT)* project template. C++/WinRT support is integrated in VS2022 or available as an [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CppWinRTTeam.cppwinrt101804264) for VS2019 (though VS2022 is recommended).

Comment: @IInspectable I got that to work now but when I compile the output of the new project is a .winmd file not a .dll file. I tried referencing it anyway but none of the namespaces or classes show up so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in this situation. In the options the output is set to a .dll which confuses me more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247760/discussion-between-doshorte-dovencio-and-iinspectable).